# Creating a form with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

Suppose I have the following file in Backbone.js:

```
  (function($){


        var FormLoanView = Backbone.View.extend({
          tagName: 'div',

          template: _.template('<% _.each(["Name","Address","Gender"],function(value) { %>' + 
            '<%= value %>' + ':<input></input><br>'  + '<% }); %>'),

          initialize: function(){
            var data = this.$el.html(this.template())
            $('body').html(data)
          }

        })


         $(document).ready(function () {

          var LoanView = new FormLoanView({
          });

        });
       })(jQuery);
```

This successfully creates the form I want. The form is 3 sets of inputs named "Name", "Address", and "Gender". This form will eventually be making a AJAX request. Anyways my question is how to deal with a form in Backbone. As it stands I currently have an array `["Name","Address","Gender"]` within my template. I did this just to make sure I was getting the right idea.

Is this data that I should be placing in a model? I am stuck here because I always saw models as dynamic data, this data will remain static. If not how could I include this the view? Any other suggestions are appreciated. I was also thinking of using jQuery within `initialize` to set this up. This would be a bad idea right? I should be reserve jQuery/DOM manipulation for more dynamic html content and use `_.template` for the static elements of my web page?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this data that I should be placing in a model?

Yes, you should.

> I am stuck here because I always saw models as dynamic data, this data will remain static. If not how could I include this the view?

Well, you don't have to if your view (form) is just there to capture the data.

What you want to do is to create [`attritube`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) and use [`model.save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) to submit the data.